# magento - importing csv into db using php script

Tags: mysql, magento

Am new to magento. I want to know how to import a huge csv file in to magento db. I have exported the csv file using profiles and updated the csv with proper values. Using php script i need to import back to magento.

Reason why i want to use php script is so that i can put this as a cron so that it excute automatically.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

There is an import/export extension we bought from xtento. It works pretty well. If they don't have something which imports what you need, I'm sure they could hand-roll something.

And my usual:

> My philosophy is to start looking at extensions before trying to code anything in magento. Is especially helpful when an upgrade breaks something; they'll usually fix upgrade problems that clearly affect their own extensions for free.

Please put lots of effort into extensions that do what you need with as little of your code as possible. :)